# Oracle/sql compare two numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a SQL/Oracle function that compares two numbers 
if  number are even like( 22,10,4,12,6..) true 
if are odd number like(3,7,13,5...) false.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_even(num_in NUMBER) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
  IF MOD(num_in, 2) = 0 THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  END IF; 
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END is_even;
/ 





CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_odd(num_in NUMBER) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
  RETURN MOD(num_in, 2) = 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END is_odd;
```

Comment: can you give the query or function how you tried to achive this

Comment: Do modulo 2 somehow.

Comment: so what is the question again?

Comment: You can also have only one function (less code to maintain), if a number is not odd it is even

Comment: i need a function to show me if number are even to be true if odd to be false

Comment: Better to return numbers (0,1)rather  than boolean. you cannot use it in sql if you return boolean.

Answer (score 1):

One  point not addressed in the other answer, which I have already mentioned in the comments and you don't seem to have paid attention to is that Boolean values can only be used in PL/SQL code, not in Oracle SQL.

This restricts you from calling your function through the most common method - to use it in  a sql statement. If you try running this query with your function, it would fail.

```
select is_even(10) FROM DUAL;
```

> ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> ORA-06553: PLS-382: expression is
>   of wrong type

You may call this function to set a Boolean PL/SQL variable, but it isn't very useful in a general scenario.

```
DECLARE 
v_even_odd BOOLEAN := is_even(3);
```

Alternatively, you could return a number or a string ( "TRUE" / "FALSE" ).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_even (num_in NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
   IF MOD (num_in, 2) = 0
   THEN
      RETURN 'TRUE';
   ELSE
      RETURN 'FALSE';
   END IF;
END is_even;
/
```

Which works fine while calling from sql.

```
select is_even(10) FROM DUAL;
IS_EVEN(10)                                                                     
----------------
TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I ready don't understand what is the difficulty here, as you yourself have provided the code for two functions above...

Anyway here you go:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_even(num_in NUMBER) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
  IF MOD(num_in, 2) = 0 THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  else 
    RETURN FALSE;
  END IF; 
END is_even;
/
```

Comment: @RaduDrosu You're welcome If it works for you do not forget to accept and up-vote.